# Pass enum to class and then return

Tags: c++, class, function, enums

I've got the following enum declared in code.cpp
and im using a switch statement that depends on the what the enum is set as.

```
enum State  { HighMoral, PoorMoral, EndGame };
State CurrentState = HighMoral;

switch (CurrentState)
{
        case HighMoral: random = rand()%3+1;
                        switch (random)
                        {
                            case 1: CurrentState = g_Solider.KillCommander(&CurrentState, random = rand()%2+1);
                            break;
                            case 2: CurrentState = g_Solider.KillSeniorCommander(&CurrentState,random = rand()%2+1);
                            break;
                            case 3: CurrentState = g_Solider.LessHalfStrength(&CurrentState);
                            break;
                        };
                        break;
        case PoorMoral: CurrentState = g_Solider.JoinSeniorCommander();
                        break;
};
```

I want to pass this enum to a function in a class and then have it return either `HighMoral`, `PoorMoral` or `EndGame` and change the current state for my switch statement.

However I'm rather clueless when it comes to passing this and returning it.
I've looked around and have had no luck in finding how to do this.

I've got 3 files. code.cpp (contains `void main()` and the `enum`), solider.h (contains solider class does not know the state enum exists (how to do this?)), solider.cpp (contains all solider code but needs to take the current state and return a new state)

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

Solider.h

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern enum State;

class Solider
{
private:
public:
    void KillSeniorCommander(State& currentState, int random); // Kill the Senior Commander or random event
    void JoinSeniorCommander(State& currentState); // Have the Commander join the group
    void DefunctGroup(State& currentState); // Disband the group
};
```

Solider.cpp

```
void Solider::KillSeniorCommander(State& currentState, int random)
{
    if (SeniorCommander==1) // If The SeniorCommander is Active
    {
        cout << "The Senior Commander has died!\n";
    SeniorCommander--; // Kill the SeniorCommander
    Groupsize--; // Reduce the Groupsize
    Strength = Strength - (5*2.5); // Remove SeniorCommanders impact on Strength
    SquadMoral = SquadMoral - (5*2.5);// Remove SeniorCommanders impact on SquadMoral
    CurrentState = PoorMoral;
}
else // Otherwise do something random
{ 
    switch (random)
    {
    case 1: cout << "Your group survives a ambush!\n"; 
            break;
    case 2: random = rand()%5+1; // Give random a new value
            if (random>1)
            {
                cout << random << " group members have died!\n"; // Kill x Aamount of members
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "A group member has died!\n"; // Kill a member
            }
            Groupsize = Groupsize - random; // Remove the members from the group
            Strength = Strength - (random*2.5); // Remove there effect Strength
            SquadMoral = SquadMoral - (random*2.5); // Remove there effect on GroupMoral
            break;
    }
    CurrentState = CurrentState;
}
} // KillSeniorCommander(int random)


void Solider::JoinSeniorCommander(State& currentState)
{
if (SeniorCommander==2 && Commander == 0) // Check to see if the Commander is dead and a
{                                         // SeniorCommander is not in service
    cout << "The Senior Commander has joined!\n";
    SeniorCommander--; // Change their status to active
    Groupsize++; // Add them to the group
    Strength = Strength - (5*2.5); // Add their impact to Strength
    SquadMoral = SquadMoral - (5*2.5); // Add their impact to GroupMoral
    CurrentState = HighMoral;
}
else // He isn't available to join
{
    cout << "You fail to recruit new command!\n";
    CurrentState = CurrentState;
}
} // JoinSeniorCommander()

void Solider::DefunctGroup(State& currentState)
{
cout << "Your group has been disbanded as it is not fit for duty.";
CurrentState = EndGame;
} // DefunctGroup()
```

code.cpp

Comment: What's wrong with `State MyFunction(State inp) { ... return HighMoral; ... }`?

Comment: Your requirements aren't very clear. You want to pass the new state and return the old state in one function? That would be `State setState(State newState) { State temp = currentState; currentState = newState; return temp; }`

Comment: I've just updated the question to try give a better explanation of what i intend to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the enum in a header and include that header in both files.

For instance:

```
#ifndef SOLDIERSTATE_H
#define SOLDIERSTATE_H

enum SoldierState
{
    HighMorale, 
    PoorMorale, 
    EndGame
};

#endif
```

Comment: This and David's answer helped me fix it - It now works - Thanks :)!

Answer (score 0):

Enums can be treated as integers in interfaces. You can use on of two approaches: Pass by reference and have the function change it intenally, or pass by value and return the next `State` by value:

```
// one or the other
void nextState( State& currentState );
State nextState( State currentState );
```

Comment: I've just updated the question with this code however - i'm still somewhat stuck :(.

Comment: @Andy: The code shows quite a few deficiencies. I encourage you to pick a good C++ book. I would not really know where to start: references, function signatures (what is returned or not)...

Comment: Basically in 'void main()' im running that 'switch statement' which is dependent on what the state is i want the 'class functions' to change that 'state' to a new one :).

Comment: @Andy: `void main` is an error, the return type must be `int`. That is why I am suggesting a starter's book. In your code it seems that there is a state per object plus the state you pass in, which is the one you want? Some other notes, you cannot assign from a function that returns `void`...

Answer (score 0):

As with everything else in C++, you need to see the declaration of something you want to use. In your case, this means the definition of `State` must be moved to a header file and this file then be included both in main.cpp and soldier.h. Then, you will be able to use the type `State` in declarations of `Soldier` member functions normally.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Game
{
    public:
        enum State { HighMoral, PoorMoral, EndGame };
        aMethod(State::PoorMoral);
};

Game::aMethod(State aState)
{
    return State::HighMoral;
}
```

Comment: In C++ enum members get the scope that contains the enum, so saying `State::HighMoral` would be incorrect.  You can get this behavior in c++11 by saying `enum class State {};`